# Можно ли переделывать внешние библиотеки, на пример, com.google.android.material.timepicker

Tags: java, android

Существует внешняя библиотека com.google.android.material.timepicker. При этом я через AndroidStudio, нажав F4, могу посмотреть исходный код классов этой библиотеки.
Я хотел бы изменить код класса TimePickerClockPresenter и переисользовать у себя изменённую библиотеку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?
Может быть можно как-то скачать весь пакет com.google.android.material.timepicker себе на локальный ПК и переделать?

Comment: Я нашёл такой ресурс https://android.googlesource.com/
но com.google.android.material.timepicker там нет

Comment: Это open source проект, делайте свой форк или просто скачивайте исходники и делайте что хотите
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/timepicker